# Maintain Undo after code runs

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code below that updated a "Last edited" column, however, every time the code runs it remove the standard Excel Undo feature.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("$B30:$O2000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yy")
    End If

End Sub
```

Is there a way to keep Undo and still use the code? or another way around of tracking the last update of the range.

Comment: No, VBA actions cannot be tracked by undo.

Comment: @Peh Is there a why to track the update without VBA then?

Comment: Look into Application.OnUndo method

Comment: @Taosique but this way I see only a chance to be able to fake the undo for writing the date but not to be able to undo the change that was made causing the `worksheet_change` to run.